# arduino c++ issues regarding class name

Tags: c++, class, arduino, arduino-ide

I am working on connecting my philips hue light bulbs to the arduino and found some resources online.
One of the resources has a file that keeps throwing an error and when I looked at it, I have never seen this syntax used before.
Can anyone help me out?

```
#ifndef SERIALHUE_H
#define SERIALHUE_H
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Stream.h>
#include <ArduinoHue.h>



class SerialHue: public ArduinoHue{
 public:
SerialHue(char* ipAddress, Stream* serial);
boolean connect(char* deviceId, char* username);
 protected:
char* _ipAddress; 
char* _deviceId;
char* _username;
boolean makePost(char* request, char* data);
boolean waitForResponse();
Stream* _serial;
};

#endif
```

The error is in this line:

****class SerialHue: public ArduinoHue{****

Giving the error:

*SerialHue.h:10: error: expected class-name before '{' token*

What is this format and what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the compiler settings...it might be possible that it tries to compile c++ code with a c compiler

about the format:

```
class X : public Y {
}
```

is the syntax of extending a class in C++

plus: check that ArduinoHue.h really defines ArduinoHue class

...if you can't figure it out: take a look at the precompiled sourcefile (g++ -E)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are not recursively including a file, like #including a file that #includes other files you have also #included.

Also, Forward declarations instead of #include ArduinoHue.h could solve your problem.  such as:

```
class ArduinoHue;
```

I have found similar questions, they might be able to help you:
[expected class-name before '{' token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199809/expected-class-name-before-token)

[error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319906/error-expected-class-name-before-token)