# Classes (located in different headers) that use each other's objects

Tags: class, header

The class called *Universes* uses a data member of type *States*, whilst *States* uses an object of type *Universes*. I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express (if that makes any difference).

States.h:

```
class Universes;

extern Universes universe;

class States
{
public:

    int relations;

    States();
};

States::States()
{
    relations = universe.state_no;
}
```

Universes.h

```
#include "States.h"

class Universes
{
public:
    States state;
    int state_no;
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#include "Universes.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Universes universe;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
States.h(16): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Universes'
States.h(1) : see declaration of 'Universes'
States.h(16): error C2228: left of '.state_no' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Header files inclusion / Forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832714/header-files-inclusion-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where you try to access `universe.state_no`, the `Universes` class is incomplete (it's forward-declared).

A clean way to fix this is to move the definition of `States::States` into `States.cpp`, and make sure `States.cpp` #includes `Universes.h`.